# Why does WSAT outperform Simulated Annealing?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, simulated-annealing, sat, wsat

on some journal i read that WSAT ( Walking SAT ) algorithm has better performances than Simulated Annealing algorithm in the resolution of SAT problem.

So my question is, can someone kindly explain why we got this result ? 
Could be because SA is more like a general purpose algorithm ?

---

Edit:
[Here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/selman/papers/pdf/93.ijcai.gsatext.pdf) maybe the most relevant document i read about.

Comment: Could you please add some details? 'some journal i read' is very unspecific. On which task was the test and other detail information are required to answer this question.

Comment: I've edited my question and added a link to one of Selman, Kautz document i read,  thanks @MrSmith42

Answer (score 2):

Simulated annealing evaluates a randomly chosen neighbor, the algorithm **always** moves to the neighbor if it is better, following an intuition from physics.  But WalkSAT does better by sometimes **not** moving to a neighbor even if it is better.

When you start solving a 3-CNF satisfiable with WalkSAT: or you already solved your problem, or some clause are unsatisfied. The fact that a clause is unsatisfied means that at least one of the variables in the clause must be flipped to find a solution. If variables are chosen randomly from the clause with length equals to 3 it is easy to see that each flip as a 33% or better chance of being correct [1].

SA does not have such high probability to succeed and has a high risk of being stuck in a local maximum...

This is how I would explain myself why WalkSAT is better than SA, but there is probably already a study on this problem ;) You should take a closer look to [this paper](http://fai.cs.uni-saarland.de/teaching/winter12-13/heuristic-search-material/WalkSAT.pdf) [2] providing a detailed comparison between SA and WalkSAT.

---

[ 1 ] Papadimitrou, C. H., & Steiglitz, K. (1982). Combinatorial optimization: algorithms and complexity. Publisher: Prentice Hall.

[ 2 ] Selman, B., Kautz, H. A., & Cohen, B. (1994). Noise strategies for improving local search. In AAAI (Vol. 94, pp. 337-343).